# Use code-prettify in javascript using local pretty.css?

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

code-prettify seems to want to grab pretty.css from a cdn, rather than use a local copy - is it possible to configure things so that it uses the local version without a network call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run_prettify.js` loads from a CDN and uses query flags to figure
out what to load:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

The `prettify.js` script gives you more control over loading but you have to remember to load the language handlers you need and call `PR.prettyPrint()` on load:

```
<head>
  <script src="/path/to/prettify.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/prettify.css" />
  <!-- You would also need to load the language handlers you need here. -->
</head>
<body onload="PR.prettyPrint()">
  ...
</body>
```

You can find `prettify.{js,css}` and the language handlers in https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src